# Caeser encryption algorithm in PHP

Tags: php, encryption

Is there a way to use Caeser encryption for a string in PHP; I have come from .net so I do not know much.

Take this example:

```
original
aaaaaa
after ceaser encryption
bbbbbb
```

Next example:

```
original
abcd
after ceaser encryption
bcde
```

Could anyone make a function out of this with `echo $output;`

Comment: The most basic of string manipulation: http://courses.gdeyoung.com/pages/encryption/CaesarCipher.php or use [str_rot13()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-rot13.php)

Comment: Please don't use this for serious encryption (e.g. passwords), even md5 hashing is more secure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one version that works with ASCII letters:

```
function caesar($str, $shift) {
    $len = strlen($str);
    $ord_alpha_upper = ord('A');
    $ord_alpha_lower = ord('a');
    $shift = $shift % 26 + 26; // takes care of negative shifts
    for($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) {
        $chr = $str[$i];
        if (ctype_upper($chr)) {
            $str[$i] = chr($ord_alpha_upper + (ord($chr) - $ord_alpha_upper + $shift) % 26);

        }
        else if (ctype_lower($chr)) {
            $str[$i] = chr($ord_alpha_lower + (ord($chr) - $ord_alpha_lower + $shift) % 26);
        }
    }

    return $str;
}
```

You can use both positive and negative shifts and it will work correctly no matter what the shift distance.

However, be aware that PHP has no concept of character encoding (strings are effectively byte arrays), so if the input is not in a single-byte encoding or UTF-8 this will not work correctly.

Comment: hello sir, how to I use this snippet, echo $str doesnt seem to work..

Comment: @user2625447: It's a function, you call it and print the results: `echo caesar('abcd', 1);`. But you would be better served by reading a basic PHP tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
<?php
/**
 * Rotate each string characters by n positions in ASCII table
 * To encode use positive n, to decode - negative.
 * With n = 13 (ROT13), encode and decode n can be positive.
 *
 * @param string $string
 * @param integer $n
 * @return string
 */

function rotate($string, $n) {

    $length = strlen($string);
    $result = '';

    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $ascii = ord($string{$i});

        $rotated = $ascii;

        if ($ascii > 64 && $ascii < 91) {
            $rotated += $n;
            $rotated > 90 && $rotated += -90 + 64;
            $rotated < 65 && $rotated += -64 + 90;
        } elseif ($ascii > 96 && $ascii < 123) {
            $rotated += $n;
            $rotated > 122 && $rotated += -122 + 96;
            $rotated < 97 && $rotated += -96 + 122;
        }

        $result .= chr($rotated);
    }

    return $result;
}

$enc = rotate('string', 6);
echo "Encoded: $enc<br/>\n";
echo 'Decoded: ' . rotate($enc, -6);

?>
```